# How to set xsl attribute using processing instruction php

Tags: php, html, xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I'm having trouble trying to set a value into the attribute using a PHP processing instruction:

**XSLT**

```
<li itemprop="startDate">
    <xsl:attribute name="content">
        <xsl:processing-instruction name="php">
            echo "Monday";
        ?</xsl:processing-instruction>
    </xsl:attribute>
    Monday
</li>
```

The page renders fine but the attribute is always empty.

**Output**

```
<li itemprop="startDate" content="">Monday</li>
```

I'm expecting the PHP to echo out a value into the attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your using PHP to transform the XML through XSLT you can use in php:

```
$proc->setParameter(null, 'day', 'Monday');

$proc->transformToXML($xml);
```

Then in your XSLT to use this variable:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl"
exclude-result-prefixes="php"
xsl:extension-element-prefixes="php">

<xsl:param name="day"/> <!-- Set the parameter -->

<xsl:attribute name='content'>
    <xsl:value-of select="$day"/>
</xsl:attribute>
```

All the best!

Answer (score 0):

You did not say how you open the XML. But because of the echo I assume it could/should have php instruction include.

The `xsl:processing-instruction` does not make sense here. Try this:

```
<li itemprop="startDate">
    <xsl:attribute name="content">
        <?php
            echo "Monday";
        ?>
    </xsl:attribute>
    Monday
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this doesn't work either. The PHP script I'm running parses the XML and XSLT together to build a file. Perhaps the problem is related to having a script include inside an attribute tag?

Comment: You have to show what your php looks like.  Perhaps [this](http://php.net/manual/de/xsltprocessor.setparameter.php) may help.